# Issue with firestore 500 writes in a batch limit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I allow import of data, which gives me a large number of documents to write in firestore. I keep a counter of documents, so I have to slow down the write.

```js
// process 75 contacts every 1200ms
return new Promise<boolean>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      timer(0, 1200)
        .pipe(
          takeWhile((_) => !!contacts.length),
        )
        .subscribe(async () => {
          const next = contacts.splice(0, 75);
          await updateContacts(userId, next);
        });
    });
```

Updating the contact works like this :-

```js
// It updates three documents: Basic, Extended and the User doc
// which has the count
export async function updateContacts(userId: string, contacts: Contact[]) {
  const firestore = admin.firestore();
  const batch = firestore.batch();
  const userRef = getUserRef(userId);

  for (const contact of contacts) {
    const basicRef = getBasicContactRef(userId);
    const extendedRef = getDetailContactRef(userId, basicRef.id);

    const basic = contact.getBasic();
    batch.set(basicRef, {
      ...basic,
      ...{ timestamp: FieldValue.serverTimestamp() },
    });

    const extended = contact.getExtended();
    batch.set(extendedRef, {
      ...extended,
      ...{ timestamp: FieldValue.serverTimestamp() },
    });

  }

  // Now update the count
  batch.update(userRef, {
    numberOfContacts: FieldValue.increment(contacts.length),
  });

  // commit it all
  return batch.commit();
}
```

However, when I run it with a large number of contacts, it fails with the following :-

> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: maximum 500 writes allowed per request

I thought I was doing fewer than 500 writes per request!

I am really scratching my head trying to figure out. I am not too smart, so asking you wise people.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the effective limit may be lower based on the exact operations you're doing. I usually can my batches at around 200-250 writes because of this. Let me see if I can find a link for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a hunch the issue is with the field transforms that your code is applying to the fields. The limit of 500 is based on the number *mutations* rather than top level document operations.  I looked up the internal code that converts the batch update/set operations to mutations, and there are some cases where there is a doubling factor:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/9bc4167d5895099ff60fd75d462cbb0d9fd8429e/packages/firestore/src/api/user_data_reader.ts#L101

So what you may be seeing is your batch of 75 generating at least 2 mutations for batch.set(basicRef), an additional 2 mutations for batch.set(extendedRef), etc. There may be some other hidden costs that I haven't traced through yet that increase the overall mutation count to > 500.

Would it be possible for you to lower the number of documents (contacts) that you pass to updateContacts()?